# Still able to review wiki edits during a review ban

Tags: bug, review, edits, tag-wiki, review-suspension

I recently failed a couple audits and got review banned. As of now:

[image]

However, I just reviewed [this wiki edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7077935):

[image]

I wasn't able to review [the related excerpt edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7077936) though:

[image]

### Additionally...

...I am able to review tag wiki edits *beyond* 20/day. All I need is the link. [Proof](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/15/mooseman?tab=activity&sort=reviews) -- as of now I've reviewed 23 edits on Lifehacks SE, the last three all tag wikis. Note I am also unable to review tag wiki excerpt edits.

Comment: Maybe wiki edits don't count. That's my guess. If not, you are a very lucky person.

Comment: @PythonMaster I'm fairly sure it's a regular ol' [tag:bug].

Comment: @bluet ... so it's a feature now?

Comment: Mooseman, I suppose that @bluet was just mocking of you a bit. I agree that it's strange, however, not necessarily a bug.